Add new DOM element in Runtime using Node JS
In my server.js, I have a listener using tmi.js that gets the comments from a twitch channel, and I want to create a new DOM element everytime a new comment appears to display it on the page.
What is the best approach for this? I've been trying EJS but I don't think that is possible using it.
Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to understand the problem. You've your own html page and on that page you want to show latest comments as they come in?

Yes this is meant to be used as an OBS overlay.

As you only need one directional communication, you can use Server sent events. Your overlay connects to your nodejs server and nodejs server will emit those events as they come in from twitch
